# Problem with Ladylux kitchen faucet sprayer

Tags: kitchens, faucet

I have a 14-year old Grohe Ladylux kitchen faucet.  Recently, the spray knob stopped working properly.  Normally when you press and release the knob, the faucet goes to spray mode until you press the release knob.  Now it only stays in spray mode if you continuously hold the spray knob down.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

For mine, it seems to be limescale or other mineral buildup.  While throughput is no longer an issue after I soak it in vinegar/water, the mechanism that switches back to plain flow isn't working and I'm very frustrated.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This is interesting, but doesn't answer the original question. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//diy.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.